# How to capture Adobe Drive requests using Fiddler?

Tags: adobe, fiddler, network-analysis, adobe-drive

I have added my DAM server as a network drive using Adobe Drive. I need to capture and inspect the requests sent by Adobe Drive to my DAM server. Can I do this using Fiddler?

I have read Fiddler help which gives steps to configure applications to use Fiddler. But I am not able to figure out how to do that with Drive.

For the testing purposes, both Drive and the server are installed on local machine.

Comment: Does DRIVE run on top of HTTP? Do the scenario work if the server *isn't* on the local machine?

Comment: @EricLaw -MSFT- - The communication between DRIVE and our DAM server happens over HTTP. About your second question, I haven't tested that scenario but as mentioned on http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/hookup.asp#Q-LocalTraffic, I have been using the machine name and not localhost in the endpoint configured in DRIVE.

Answer (score 1):

I have not used Fiddler, but there is a utility [RawCap](http://www.netresec.com/?page=RawCap), this allows to capture the localhost requests using

```
RawCap.exe 127.0.0.1 localhost_capture.pcap
```

After this use Adobe Drive, the requests are captured in this. This file (.pcap) can be opened with [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/download.html). This shows the network traffic of actions done using Adobe Drive.

[image: Captured network traffic]

There is a [Adobe Companion App](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/administer/integration/companion-app.html) which is coming with AEM 6.1. This can be used to browse DAM, transfer files like Adobe Drive, also manual action of "Check in" is not required in this. This information is not directly related to question but related to Adobe Drive. Adding this, in case some one reaches this thread for Adobe Drive, information can be of some help.